# Slideshow Function cycles through once then fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow

I'm trying to write a function that slides through a set of images within a div, then cycles back when it reaches the end (and vice/versa when going the other direction). The problem is, it's able to go through a cycle once, but screws up whenever a second cycle comes around. What am I doing wrong?

The HTML:

```
<img class="slide">
<img class="slide">
<img class="slide">
```

The JavaScript:

```
var slideNumber = 0;
var totalSlides = $('.slide').length;


$(document).ready(function(){

 var animateSlide = function(){

    $('.slide').eq(slideNumber).css('z-index', totalSlides);

    }

    $('.page-right').click(function(){

        if(slideNumber < totalSlides){

             $('.slide').eq(slideNumber).css('z-index', totalSlides-1);

             slideNumber = slideNumber + 1;

            return animateSlide();

        }

        else if(slideNumber === totalSlides) {

             $('.slide').eq(slideNumber).css('z-index', totalSlides-1);

             slideNumber = 0;

             return animateSlide();

        }

     });


     $('.page-left').click(function() {

       if (slideNumber < totalSlides) {

         $('.slide').eq(slideNumber).css('z-index', totalSlides-1);

         slideNumber = slideNumber - 1;

         return animateSlide(); 

       }

       else if(slideNumber === 0) {

         $('.slide').eq(slideNumber).css('z-index', totalSlides-1);

         slideNumber = totalSlides;

         return animateSlide(); 


      }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this would be to use addClass and removeClass. Create a css class called top slide that changes the z-index of a slide:

```
.slide{
    z-index: 1; 
}
.topSlide{
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Now just add the class to the next slide and remove the class from the previous slide:

```
var $slides = $('.slides'),
    numSlides = $slides.length;
    index = 0;    
function nextSlide(){
    $slides.eq(index % numSlides).removeClass('top-slide');
    $slides.eq(++index % numSlides).addClass('top-slide');
}
```

Not that eq indexes starting from 0, so start your first slide off with the class top-slide. Now when you call nextSlide, index will be incremented. The % (modulo) just checks the remainder against the # of slides. For example when index = 3 (and numSlides = 3), then the 3 % 3 = 0, so it will set the first slide to the top slide. When index = 4, then 4 % 3 = 1, so the second slide will be set to the top, etc...

Let me know if this makes sense!